# Creating a class with methods

Tags: python-3.x, class, python-3.5

I wrote a class named car with the attributes model, year, and speed. It also has 3 methods which are accelerate, brake, honk_horn. I'm trying to get 5 added every time accelerate is called but I can't get it to work. What am I doing wrong here?

```
class Car:
    """Defines the Car class.
       Data attributes: model of type str
                        year of type int
                        speed of type float
    """

    def __init__(self, model, year, speed=0):
        """Creates new Car object with specified model, year, and speed"""
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
        self.speed = speed

    def accelerate(self):
        self.speed + 5 #everytime it is called

    def brake(self):
        if self.speed != 0: #If speed already zero don't minus 5
            self.speed - 5
        else:
            self.speed

    def honk_horn(self):
        print("{} goes 'beep beep'".format(self.model))
```

I am supposed to get 35 when testing using the test below but I only get 30:

```
my_car = Car("Zastava", 2001, 30)
my_car.accelerate()
my_car.accelerate()
my_car.brake()
print(my_car.speed)
```

Comment: You have to do `self.speed = self.speed+5` or `self.speed+=5`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not assigning a value to `self.speed`. You as simply performing maths without using the result.

change statement below:

```
self.speed + 5 #everytime it is called
```

to this:

```
self.speed = self.speed + 5 #everytime it is called
```

or this:

```
self.speed += 5 #everytime it is called
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        self.speed + 5 #everytime it is called
```

should be

```
        self.speed += 5 #everytime it is called
```

Where I added a += instead of just +

Additionally, your `brake` function is wrong in a similar way

Answer (score 0):

change`self.speed + 5`to`self.speed = self.speed + 5`
change`self.speed - 5`to`self.speed = self.speed - 5`
that should work